# Dynamic Dropdown Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a dynamic dropdown button that functions like a option button. The reason I want it to be a button it because I can more freely effect the way it looks. I'm using bootstrap btw.

I tried to make my own and when that didn't I found a working one and tried to insert it into my page to see if it worked. It didn't

The code I copied is [here](http://www.bootply.com/64302). The only thing I changed was the in the js file i surrounded the code with a (function($){  }) to make sure the $ was defined. Still nothing.

The drop down functionality works, it just wont update the text alue of the button which is important to me. Any help is very appreciated!

My relevant code. Below is my head,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="C:\Users\Tiko\Documents\jQuery\LoLCoach\Assets\favicon.ico">

  <title>League of Legends - GG WP</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="../LoLCoach/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="LoLCoach.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../LoLCoach/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js">   </script><![endif]-->
  <script src="../LoLCoach/Assets/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="../LoLCoach/Assets/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="dropdown.js"></script>
</head>
```

Like I said, it's pretty much copy pasted from the link because I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
    <form action="/output/" name="InputCacheCheck" method="post">
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
    <div class="btn-group">

        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" name="recordinput" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Record
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CNAME</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">MX</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">PTR</a></li>
        </ul>
    <input class=".input-large" name="hostnameinput" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Lookup</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is the bootstrap.js file referenced in the head.

```
(function($) {
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
var selText = $(this).text();
$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span   class="caret"></span>');
});
        });
```

It's all kind of sloppy because I'm pretty new at this but hopefully this helps.

Comment: your code is fine make sure jquery is included, if included it looks like it is conflicting with somw other js library

Comment: your problem is not clear maybe you have to add the jquery library...

Comment: a link to code that works doesn't help anyone resolve your specific problem. Create a demo that replicates your issue as well as provide the code directly in the question

Comment: The frustrating part is that when I copy my code into the Bootply environment, it works. When I try to run it on my page by changing the button, it doesn't.